# Android open activity in foreground when phone is locked

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I want to open activity in foreground when phone is locked from Activity, which is in background. Only what I need, is waking phone, because activity starting, but phone screen is black.

Comment: Please check the guidelines for asking questions on Stackoverflow. For example post some code of what you have already tried and provide some pointers to  documentation you have already consulted.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable button for lock, and that your activity will remain in active mode. Also you can trigger broadcast reciever for starting your activity when lock button is pressed.